# combo box reference not working in access query criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have a database built that, after all of the queries are done, it will spit out a form and I can filter through records and the relevant information will change as I filter through. To get there, I have to be able to reference a combo box located on my entry form (which contains all of the sales guys' ID numbers) in my queries. However, when I input the normal form reference in the criteria section '[Forms]![Entry Form]![ID]' and run the queries, it returns nothing. I figure that this is because in a lot of our live data tables, the ID numbers have spaces before or after them, which they have no spaces in the ID numbers listed in the combo box. I tried to use the trim function in my queries for the ID number field in the tables, but it still returned nothing.

Any advice on what else I can try? If more info is needed, ask away.

Comment: Like might work for you, although it will be slower: LIKE \*ID* in the criteria.

Comment: I modified it to say: Like [Forms]![Entry Form]![ID], but it didn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: I also tried: Like *[Forms]![Entry Form]![ID]* (this is supposed to have asterisks around it, but they disappear), but it didn't do anything either

Comment: Please post a little sample data. Are you sure that the spaces are spaces and not a character that looks like a space?

Comment: I changed it to Like "*" & [Forms]![Entry Form]![ID] & "*" (again there are supposd to be asterisks in between parenthesis, but they disappear) and it worked.. kind of. It returns data, but it doesn't seem to be all correct. It returns somewhat random data, from what I can tell- but data nonetheless. Any idea on what change I should make here?

Comment: I figured it out!! The answer to my problem was I needed to manually type in the combo box options instead of importing the options from another table. For some reason that worked. Thanks for you guys' help again!

Answer (score 1):

Change the Bound Column to 2, or whatever column it is in the row column, all under the property sheet data tab for combo box.  It may be returning the ID rather than the text when selecting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where the query designer isn't the best option.  Instead, open it in SQL mode (there should be a dropdown in the upper left corner that allows you to change how you view the query) and change the WHERE clause to something like:

```
Trim(ID) = [Forms]![Entry Form]![ID]
```

It's not going to be very efficient, this is why you should never use bound forms because you can do the trimming on data entry and save on the overhead, but this should at least return data for you.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, unfortunately. I appreciate the help though

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!! The answer to my problem was I needed to manually type in the combo box options instead of importing the options from another table. For some reason that worked. Thanks for you guys' help again!